# Select Html Tags with Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to select all Html tags code with Jsoup

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
 .....
 </body>
</html>
```

I tried that:

```
Document dc = Jsoup.parse(fichier, "utf-8");
String tags = dc.outerHtml();
```

Comment: ...and what was the output from your attempt? For us to help out with your question, we'll need more context: check out the guidelines on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you add example of what exactly you want to select and how is it different from what you are getting with your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question it's not clear, but it seems that you simply want to get all the tag node names, to do so you can parse the html and `getAllElements()` and then iterate over the list element getting the `nodeName()` of each one, using java 8 to take advantage of `forEach` your code could be something like:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JSoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String fichier = "<html>" +
                            "<head></head>" +
                            "<body></body>" +
                            "</html>";
        Document dc = Jsoup.parse(fichier, "utf-8");
        Elements elements = dc.getAllElements();
        elements.forEach( element -> System.out.println(element.nodeName()));
    }
}
```

This code prints all the tag node names:

```
#document
html
head
body
```